# How to process files based on their date in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two sort of files, `xml files` and `txt files`. The files have a date in their name. If the date of the `xml file` matches the date of a `txt file` I want to open the `txt file` do some processing and write the output to a list. After that I want to change the `xml file`. Multiple `xml files` can have the same date but the `txt file` is unique so this means that more then 1 `xml file` can be linked with a `txt file.`

Right now I have a problem. my `to_csv` list contains data of both 20200907 and 20201025. I don't want it to work like that. I want my `to_csv` list just do one file (and thus one date) at a time.

```
output_xml = r"c:\desktop\energy\XML_Output"
output_txt = r"c:\desktop\energy\TXT_Output"

xml_name = os.listdir(output_xml )
txt_name = os.listdir(output_txt)
txt_name = [x.replace('-', '') for x in txt_name] #remove the - in the filenames

# Extract the date from the xml and txt files. 
xml_dates = []
for file in xml_name:
    find = re.search("_(.\d+)-", file).group(1)
    xml_dates.append(find)

txt_dates = []
for file in txt_name:
    find = re.search("MM(.+?)AB", file).group(1)
    txt_dates.append(find)

#THIS IS SOME REPRODUCABLE OUTPUT FROM WHAT IS RECEIVED FROM ABOVE SNIPPET.
xml_dates = ['20200907', '20200908', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025']
txt_dates = ['20200907', '20201025']

to_csv = []

for date_xml in xml_dates:
    for date_txt in txt_dates:
        if date_xml == date_txt:

              match_txt = [s for s in txt_name if date_txt in s]  # matching txt file  
              match_xml = [s for s in xml_name if date_xml in s]  # matching xml file

              match_txt_temp = match_txt[0]
              match_txt_score = [match_txt_temp[:6]+'-'+match_txt_temp[6:8]+'-'+match_txt_temp[8:10]+'-'+match_txt_temp[10:12]+match_txt_temp[12:]]

              with open(output_txt + "/" + match_txt_score[0], "r") as outer:
                reader = csv.reader(outer, delimiter="\t")  

                for row in reader:
                    read = [row for row in reader if row]
                    for row in read:
  
                        energy_level = row[20]

                        if energy_level > 250:
                            to_csv.append(row)
                            
print(to_csv)
```

**Current output:**

```
[['1', '2', '3', '20200907', '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20200907', '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20200907', '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20201025, '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20201025, '4', '5']]
```

**Desired output:**

```
[[['1', '2', '3', '20200907', '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20200907', '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20200907', '4', '5']], 
['1', '2', '3', '20201025, '4', '5'], 
['1', '2', '3', '20201025, '4', '5']]
```

Comment: @Iguananaut no they are not the same. In the desired output I have a list inside a last seperated by date. In current output its all in one

Comment: Yes, I saw that.

Comment: @Iguananaut if you have an other idea to tackle this just let me know, Im not a fan of such a nested list but could not find any other solution

Comment: Based on the code you provided you could simplify this greatly by getting rid of the double for-loop and the if statement.  If you have two lists `xml_dates` and `txt_dates` you could process the dates that match simply by taking the set intersection of the two `matching_dates = set(xml_dates).intersection(txt_dates)` and then loop over `matching_dates`.  You also have some other bugs I think, like double-looping over `reader` (you have some `[row for row in reader if row]` inside a for-loop over `reader`, which doesn't make sense).

Comment: @Iguananaut could you show it in an answer? That also gives me the opportunity to accept your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I could give an exact solution because you didn't explain what `output_t2m` or `match_t2m_score` are or how they relate to the names of the files you want to open or the dates (as your example code is written it will always read the same file).

Comment: output_t2m is the just a path, match_t2m_score is the file name

Comment: But which file name?  As written `match_t2m_score[0]` is *always* the same value in your loop.  It's not clear how it relates to `txt_dates` or `xml_dates`.

Comment: Can we move this to a chat? It requires some explanation

Comment: It would probably be best if you provided a [Minimum, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Then it would require less explanation.

Comment: @Iguananaut okay I changed my code. You can use it and see how I get the data, I just added the xml_dates and t2m_dates as reproducable data

Comment: Thank you that does help.  If I understand properly, are you reading the same CSV file multiple times?  You say there are N XML files with the same date to 1 CSV file with that date.  Why not just read each of the CSV files and then duplicate the same data N times for each XML file with the matching date.  In other words, what is this task you're *actually* trying to accomplish, since it's not clear that you aren't just duplicating the same data over and over.

Comment: @Iguananaut the actual task is to process a txt_file for every matching xml_file (multiple xml_files can match with one txt_file). For every match I want to open the txt_file and write its output to to_csv list

Comment: Right, you explained that, but if there is only one text file per date, why re-read that file multiple times if it's just going to be duplicates of the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you have only one txt file by date and only want to process xml files if they are linked to a txt file. That means that one single loop over txt_dates is enough:

```
...
for date_txt in txt_dates:
    date_xml = date_txt

    match_txt = [s for s in txt_name if date_txt in s]  # the matching txt file  
    match_xml = [s for s in xml_name if date_xml in s]  # possible matching xml files
    if len(match_xml) == 0:   # no matching xml files
        continue

    match_txt_temp = match_txt[0]
    match_txt_score = [match_txt_temp[:6]+'-'+match_txt_temp[6:8]+'-'
                       +match_txt_temp[8:10]+'-'+match_txt_temp[10:12]
                       +match_txt_temp[12:]]

    # prepare a new list for that date
    curr = list()

    with open(output_txt + "/" + match_txt_score[0], "r") as outer:
        reader = csv.reader(outer, delimiter="\t")  

        for row in reader:
            read = [row for row in reader if row]
            for row in read:
                energy_level = row[20]
                if energy_level > 250:
                    curr.append(row)

    if len(curr) > 0:    # if the current date list is not empty append it
        to_csv.append(curr)
                        
print(to_csv)
```

BEWARE: as what you have provided is not a reproducible example I could not test the above code and typos are possible...

Answer (score 0):

You could append rows to a dictionary instead of an array to allow to keep rows separated using a key representing the dates. And after parsing the files you can create whatever list composition you want from the dictionary.

```
xml_dates = ['20200907', '20200908', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025']
txt_dates = ['20200907', '20201025']

to_csv = {'20200907': [], '20201025':[]}

for date_xml in xml_dates:
    for date_txt in txt_dates:
        if date_xml == date_txt:
             with open(output_t2m + "/" + match_t2m_score[0], "r") as outer:
                reader = csv.reader(outer, delimiter="\t")  

                for row in reader:
                    read = [row for row in reader if row]
                    for row in read:
  
                        energy_level = row[20]

                        if energy_level > 250:
                            to_csv[date_txt].append(row)

final_csv = [to_csv['20200907'], to_csv['20201025']]
```

Comment: this is very inflexible. the date of the files change constantly so I cant hard code 20200907 and 20201025

Comment: It's really.  I would amend this answer to start with an empty dict, or use a `defaultdict`, like `to_csv = defaultdict(list)`.  Nevertheless, the above answer still has the same bugs as your code too.

Comment: It's also not necessary to use a `dict` for this at all.  This can be done much more simply, however it's not clear how to provide the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through `txt_dates` first then I think you can achieve your desired output. You can see that the dates in `txt_date` are grouped together so you get one date at a time.

```
xml_dates = ['20200907', '20200908', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025']
txt_dates = ['20200907', '20201025']

# sample csv data for each xml_date since we don't have the actual file contents
xml_rows = {
    "20200907": ["a,b,c", "1,2,3", "10,11,12"],
    "20201025": ["a,c,b", "7,8,9"]
}

to_csv = []

for date_txt in txt_dates:
    # Filter xml_dates for those that match the current date_txt
    xml_matches = [xd for xd in xml_dates if xd == date_txt]
    print("txt date:", date_txt)
    for date_xml in xml_matches:
        print("    ", date_xml, end=" ")
        # simulate rows in a csv file
        file_rows = [row.split(",") + [date_xml] for row in xml_rows[date_xml]]
        to_csv.append(file_rows)
    print()

print(to_csv)
```

Result:

```
txt date: 20200907
     20200907
txt date: 20201025
     20201025      20201025      20201025      20201025
[[['a', 'b', 'c', '20200907'],
  ['1', '2', '3', '20200907'],
  ['10', '11', '12', '20200907']],
 [['a', 'c', 'b', '20201025'],
  ['7', '8', '9', '20201025']],
 [['a', 'c', 'b', '20201025'],
  ['7', '8', '9', '20201025']],
 [['a', 'c', 'b', '20201025'],
  ['7', '8', '9', '20201025']],
 [['a', 'c', 'b', '20201025'],
  ['7', '8', '9', '20201025']]]
```

**Edit: explanation of the `file_rows` line**

```
file_rows = [row.split(",") + [date_xml] for row in xml_rows[date_xml]]
```

This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The idea is to mimic processing a csv file. The `xml_rows[date_xml]` is a list such as what might be created with

```
xml_rows = {}
date_xml = "2021-09-27"
with open("data.csv") as fd:
   xml_rows[date_xml] = [line.strip() for line in fd]
```

where `data.csv` contains

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
10,11,12
```

Note that there are more robust ways to process csv files, e.g. by using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library.

Given the `xml_rows[date_xml]` list, the script then splits each row by comma with `row.split(",")`. If we did

```
for row in xml_rows[date_xml]:
    print(row, "=>", row.split(","))
```

The output would be

```
a,b,c => ['a', 'b', 'c']
1,2,3 => ['1', '2', '3']
10,11,12 => ['10', '11', '12']
```

To make it clear where these lines came from, I appended the date using `row.split(",") + [date_xml]` so the list would have the date that was being processed. So

```
for row in xml_rows[date_xml]:
    print(row, "=>", row.split(",") + ["2021-09-27"])
```

would produce

```
a,b,c => ['a', 'b', 'c', '2021-09-27']
1,2,3 => ['1', '2', '3', '2021-09-27']
```

Since I was mocking the input data anyway, this all might have been more clear with

```
xml_dates = ['20200907', '20200908', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025', '20201025']
txt_dates = ['20200907', '20201025']

# sample csv data for each xml_date since we don't have the actual file contents
xml_rows = {
    "20200907": [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"], ["10", "11", "12"]],
    "20201025": [["a", "c", "b"], ["7", "8", "9"]]
}

to_csv = []

for date_txt in txt_dates:
    # Filter xml_dates for those that match the current date_txt
    xml_matches = [xd for xd in xml_dates if xd == date_txt]
    print("txt date:", date_txt)
    for date_xml in xml_matches:
        print("    ", date_xml, end=" ")
        # Append the date currently being processed to the row
        file_rows = [row + [date_xml] for row in xml_rows[date_xml]]
        to_csv.append(file_rows)
    print()

print(to_csv)
```

Comment: I dont understand your `file_rows`

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but since I dont need to mimic any csv files I get confused. What do I need to use instead of `file_rows = [row + [date_xml] for row in xml_rows[date_xml]]`

Comment: You would replace the `file_rows = ...` line with whatever processing you need to do for the file that matches. It looks like you are opening a file and filtering the lines based on some values. If you put that in a function, say `process_csv_file()`, then you could replace my `file_rows = ...` with `process_csv_file()`. Since you are using `csv.reader` I infer that your input is a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, and on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69345582/how-to-process-files-based-on-their-date-in-python?noredirect=1#comment122567374_69345582) I can tell you that the following would be equivalent to what you're trying to do, though it doesn't seem very useful, because you're just duplicating the contents of the CSV files for each XML file with a matching date:

```py
xml_file_re = re.compile(r'_(.\d+)-')
xml_dates = defaultdict(int)
for filename in os.listdir(output_xml):
    if m := re.search("_(.\d+)-", file):
        xml_dates[m.group(1)] += 1

txt_file_re = re.compile(r'MM(.+?)AB')
csv_by_date = []

for filename in os.listdir(output_txt):
    if not m := txt_file_re.search(filename):
        continue

    date = m.group(1)

    if date not in xml_dates:
        continue

    with open(os.path.join(output_txt, filename)) as fobj:
        reader = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter='\t')
        # Take only rows with energy_level > 250
        rows = [row for row in reader if row[20] > 250]
        # Make a list of copies of the row for each matching XML file
        # Here we make duplicates of the rows just to be on the safe side...
        copies = [rows[:] for _ in range(xml_dates[date])]
        csv_by_date.append(copies)
```

Again, this is equivalent to what you seem to be wanting to do, but I'm not sure what it accomplishes for you (especially where the XML files come in...)

Comment: Im not just duplicating the content of a csv file for each xml file with a matching date. Im checking if a certain row has a higher value then 250 (the energy_level). After that Im writing the output to a list

Comment: A single row contains multiple values. In your example code it's checking if a certain column (in your code `row[20]`, which I guess is "energy_level") contains a value. And for now that seems to be hard-coded, so the contents of the same CSV file will always be the same. You're just duplicating it.

Comment: Only the rows who have an energy_level of > 250 are being put into to_csv. From my experience I can tell you that its probably 10% of the file data that is being put into to_csv. To answer your other question, I re-read a txt file only if it matches with the same xml date. If I have multiple xml dates that match with a txt date then yes I do read re-read. don't see the problem of it.

Comment: By the way. Operator :- requier python 3.8 or higher. I have 3.7

Comment: No big deal, you just have to replace that with `m = ...; if m: ...`

Comment: "If I have multiple xml dates that match with a txt date then yes I do read re-read. don't see the problem of it."  The problem is it's overcomplicating things for you.  If you read my answer, what you're doing is exactly equivalent to reading that CSV file once, then duplicating it N times where N is the number of XML files containing the same date in the filename.  It seems almost superfluous.

Comment: Oke so reading a CSV file once and processing it N times where N is the number of XML files is better. I agree with you. Is that what your answer is doing also? By the way can you change that m = thing in your code? I edited it but still get an error... thank you